# Файл лога не уменьшается в размере

Tags: sql-server

Жила-была небольшая база, размером 15Гиг на MSSQL 2012
метода восстановления Простой
в какой-то момент файл с журналом вырос до максимального размера указанного в настройках и резервные копии каждый день начали прибавлять по 2 гига
процедура сжатия файлов не запускается.

как почистить файл с логом и сделать размер резервной копии вменяемого размера, сейчас она уже 70 Гигов

Comment: Для начала посмотрите почему не освобождается файл `select log_reuse_wait_desc, * from sys.databases`

Comment: @DenisRubashkin, пишет что REPLICATION, это может мешать ?

Comment: Конечно может, пока все подписчики не получат результат транзакции, транзакция не может быть помечена как неактивная. Проверьте  работу репликации, все ли там нормально.